# Ruby: new line in while loop

Tags: ruby, while-loop

How can I add a new line (with a new string) after 'done' is recived?

> `while (input = gets.chomp) != "done"
>   ...
>   end`

Comment: Add a new line to what?

Answer (score 1):

Everything that is after the loop happens after "done" is received.

so...

```
while (input = gets.chomp) != "done"
  ...
end
puts
puts "someone typed 'done' so I'm now showing this text."
```

Comment: I don't believe you need the first "puts". Puts will automatically place the string that comes after it on a new line.

Comment: We don't know what the while loop does but if it doesn't do its last output with a new line then to meet OP's original explicit request we may need the puts  @leok

Comment: Good Point @SteveTurczyn